# Error: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native, expo, yarnpkg

I keep getting this error whenever I run yarn install on my React Native app. I'm trying to update React Native to version 44 from 39, but I keep getting this error when I try to install anything at all:

```
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
Arguments:
Directory: D:\new\new-mobile\node_modules\grpc
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@14.15.0 | win32 | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "D:\new\new-mobile\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/node-v83-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.2 and node@14.15.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error socket hang up
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
gyp info using node@14.15.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
gyp info using node@14.15.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.6.8 found at "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe"gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.7.30621.155) found at:
gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\new\\new-mobile\\node_modules\\grpc\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.15.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.15.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\HP\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\14.15.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\new\\new-mobile\\node_modules\\grpc',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\new\\new-mobile\\node_modules\\grpc\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
gyp info using node@14.15.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
gyp info spawn args ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
```

^ this is only a part of the error I'm getting; it's quite long otherwise.

Can someone tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The part that you posted says that the installation was not able to find a prebuilt binary for the native Node.js addon `grpc` for your platform so it will be rebuilt from sources.